# Prioritize recently used commands in fzf

Tags: plugin-fzf, command-history

I use [fzf's](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) `:History:` a lot to execute previous Vim commands, it's really handy.

I'd like to give Vim commands that I used more recently a better ranking so they appear as the best match when using `:History:`.

For example, I execute `:History`, type "lg", and see a couple of results:

```
1000  norm iLooking good
173  /LBS//gc
436  /lstGrepTestFile/lstGrepFileColor/gc
```

The bottom result (command number 436) is the best match according to fzf: When I hit enter, the command is executed.

But the command I really want to be the best match, instead of 436, is command number 1000: `norm iLooking good`.

This is also the command I execute the most often and also the most recently via fzf in Vim.

Currently, I have to move the selection in fzf's results two lines up to select the desired command.

Is there a way to prioritize commands in the output of fzf in Vim based on which one is the most recently used?

Comment: Instead of using History, create some mappings or commands for frequent tasks? (Just a thought)

Comment: I use mappings too, but I'm running out of mnemonic keystrokes.

Comment: That's fair; using `<leader>`/`<localleader>` and "prefixes" helped me organize a bit (and my plugin popsikey helps me not forget the mappings). Happy to [chat] more about the mappings/commands, but I don't have a FZF answer